# Please vote thanks =)

Tags: discussion, announcement

Not really a question, more a suggestion. Looking at the site for the last few weeks I notice there is not a lot of voting going on. As a result you do not have a large user base who can access the various tools

https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote

https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Users need 500 rep to vote to close questions and 1,000 rep to edit.

Only 12 users with over 1,000 rep.

IMO best way to grow is to grow your user base and in my observation with the way this site works is that it is easy for new users with low reputation get frustrated due to lack of privileges.

I am NOT suggesting you merely vote in new users just to have them, but be aware that voting is important to growing your site, especially up votes to new users.

Also, please understand I am not personally soliciting votes either , I have all the reputation and more from other sites here. I am a Vegetarian, however, and would like to see this site grow out of beta.

Upvoting new, quality questions from new users is just as important as downvoting bad or poor quality questions.

While you in beta I highly suggest commenting on poor quality questions to stimulate both high quality questions and growth.

Comment: I think the lack of voting corresponds to the lack of general activity. In general, I think the voting patterns are pretty good when there is a question/answer to vote on but the lack of these creates the real stagnation. As an (overly?) avid voter I appreciate you call to arms though, I too think voting is an important part of the SE format, I just do not think this is where the problem lies for this particular site.